# What is the dimension reduction method to large numbers of independent features while only two of them are important?why?

Tags: feature-selection, feature-extraction, pca, dimensionality-reduction

What is the dimension reduction method to model a data with large numbers of independent features (for instance 5k features), while only two of them are important (are effective in cost function)? 
I have tried on PCA!

Comment: There's many more than one way to perform dimension reduction!  How do you know only two of them are important? How many data-points do you have (more or less than 5k)? What kind of algorithm are you trying to train (classifier or regressor)?

Comment: I don't get the point of the question... I may be wrong, but, if the cost function takes into account only 2 features, why not throwing away the other 4998? It seems that your problem only has 2 features, not 5k

Comment: We do not know which features are these 2 features! Just we know only two of them are important